# DATE_ADD() with TIME column type to Expire a record

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, **KEY_TYPE** and **USER_KEY**:

```
CREATE TABLE `KEY_TYPE` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `internal_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_application_internal_name` (`internal_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `USER_KEY` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `key_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CREATE_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to `DELETE` a **USER_KEY** once it's **CREATE_DATE** plus the **KEY_TYPE.expiration** is greater than `NOW()`. I'm going to set up an *event* to accomplish this (assuming this is best practice?). However, I can't figure out how to add the Time data type **expiration** column to the **CREATE_DATE** column properly. I think I'm close, but the `DATE_ADD` is adding more than 24 hours for example to the **CREATE_DATE**. So far my query is as follows:

```
SELECT USER_KEY.create_date, KEY_TYPE.expiration,
DATE_ADD(USER_KEY.create_date, INTERVAL KEY_TYPE.expiration SECOND) CREATE_PLUS_EXPIRATION
FROM USER_KEY
JOIN KEY_TYPE ON USER_KEY.key_type_id = KEY_TYPE.id;
```

I've been playing around on DB Fiddle with the following [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7z9XqKsbKXx8WAkC3T4CA/0).

Comment: Have you tried time_to_sec https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

Comment: No, I did not @P.Salmon, just tried it out in DB fiddle and it looks like it worked. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7z9XqKsbKXx8WAkC3T4CA/1) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @P.Salmon for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up changing the `INTERVAL SECOND` to `INTERVAL HOUR_SECOND` which seemed to do the trick.

This is the event I ended up with:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT EVENT_EXPIRE_USER_KEYS
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO
        DELETE USER_KEY
        FROM USER_KEY
        JOIN KEY_TYPE ON USER_KEY.key_type_id = KEY_TYPE.id
        WHERE  DATE_ADD(USER_KEY.create_date, INTERVAL KEY_TYPE.expiration HOUR_SECOND)  < NOW();
```

But this also works as well :

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT EVENT_EXPIRE_USER_KEYS
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO
        DELETE USER_KEY
        FROM USER_KEY
        JOIN KEY_TYPE ON USER_KEY.key_type_id = KEY_TYPE.id
        WHERE  DATE_ADD(USER_KEY.create_date, INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(KEY_TYPE.expiration) SECOND)  < NOW();
```